# Can I level up Blacksmithing and Jewelcrafting at the same time easily?

Tags: diablo-iii

I'm playing with my boyfriend, and he recommended one of us go Smithing and the other go Jewelcrafting, however I still haven't found the jewelcrafting guy yet and have a decent amount of money, so have been considering putting some money into smithing anyways for when hes not around.

Are you capable of easily leveling Blacksmithing and Jewelcrafting at the same time? Or if playing with someone else, is it a better idea to have each person focus on one of the two?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The Blacksmith costs more gold to level than the Jeweler.

[Much more.](https://gaming.stackexchange.com/a/66123/336)

At all likelyhood, you'll be easily able to keep the Jeweler at a similar level to your character (that is, making gems of the appropriate level) while the blacksmith will start to lag behind.

At any rate, the bottleneck and primary gold sink is definitely the blacksmith, so leveling up the two at the same time is definitely viable, simply because the total cost of the Jewler is essentially an afterthought.

Comment: Thanks, although it should be noted that although it is easier to level Jewelcrafting, it [costs a small fortune to use the profession](http://gaming.stackexchange.com/a/68048/8462) :)

Comment: You are aware you linked to an answer that I, myself, had written, yes? haha

Comment: Yes :) I added that note for others that read your answer since this question has been viewed almost 3k times