# How much does it cost to combine a gem?

Tags: diablo-iii

On the AH it seems like the cost to buy some of the gems outright is cheaper than it is to combine 3 lesser gems, but I don't have any to check.  How much does it cost (in gold and materials) to combine gems between each quality level?

Answer (score 30, accepted):

In case you were interested in the cumulative costs:

[image: Cumulative costs starting with chipped gems]

Rather than starting with a Chipped gem, here are cumulative costs starting with Flawless Squares (the highest rank gem that drops):

[image: Cumulative costs starting with flawless squares]

Answer (score 22):

I've listed all of the costs below. Remember, that this is the cost *in addition to* the gems of the previous level.

*The recipes below require **2 gems** of the previous level*

- Rank 1 **Chipped**: n/a
- Rank 2 **Flawed**: 10 gold
- Rank 3 **Regular**: 25 gold
- Rank 4 **Flawless**: 40 gold
- Rank 5 **Perfect**: 55 gold and 1 Page of Jewelcrafting
- Rank 6 **Radiant**: 70 gold and 2 Pages of Jewelcrafting
- Rank 7 **Square**: 80 gold 1 Tome of Jewelcrafting
- Rank 8 **Flawless Square**: 100 gold and 2 Tomes of Jewelcrafting

---

*The gems below do not drop and must be crafted using **3 gems** of the previous level*

- Rank 9 **Perfect Square**: 30,000 gold and 3 Tomes of Secrets
- Rank 10 **Radiant Square**: 50,000 gold and 6 Tomes of Secrets
- Rank 11 **Star**: 80,000 gold  and 9 Tomes of Secrets
- Rank 12 **Flawless Star**: 100,000 gold and 12 Tomes of Secrets
- Rank 13 **Perfect Star**: 200,000 gold and 15 Tomes of Secrets
- Rank 14 **Radiant Star**: 400,000 gold and 20 Tomes of Secrets

Thankfully, Gems in *Diablo III* are reusable, so you won't have to recreate Rank 14 gems every time you get a new socketed upgrade.

Comment: Might want to add that flawless square is the highest possible drop, and you'll need 729 of those in total to get a Radiant Star.

Comment: @RavenDreamer Also, if you disenchant an item with a gem, it'll give your gem back.

Comment: Stats fixed. Man, Rank 14 is expensive.