# Levelling Jeweller in Diablo 3

Tags: diablo-iii

I am thinking of levelling Covetous Shen instead of the Blacksmith.

Is there anything good about levelling him to 10 first than the Blacksmith? (Other than the achievement, that is.)

Also, does anyone have a chart of craft materials needed for all of the gems?

Comment: [How much does it cost to combine a gem?](http://gaming.stackexchange.com/questions/68046/how-much-does-it-cost-to-combine-a-gem)

Comment: what about benefits of levelling Covetous Shen?

Comment: @RenoYeo You can create better gems.  That's it.

Comment: whaaaaaaaaaat. i was hearing about how you might get better crafting mats if you levelled the blacksmith to 10 for salvage and stuff.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The Blacksmith will probably give you more than the Jeweler

Jewlecrafting is so [expensive to use](https://gaming.stackexchange.com/questions/68046/how-much-does-it-cost-to-combine-a-gem) that it's not worth using at all unless you're combining Flawless Squares or higher, which is the point they stop dropping. The cost of combining those is 30k, so you can wait to level your jeweler until you start getting that kind of money.

In contrast, I find Blacksmithing is great for gearing out lower-level characters, or when you feel like gambling and trying to make good gear (your money is currently better-spent at the AH if you want some guarented good gear though)

Also, here's a list of [what you will need to combine each gem type](https://gaming.stackexchange.com/a/68048/8462)

Answer (score 1):

I would go so far as to say the blacksmith is obselete at this point. 
The jeweler is just over-priced. Leveling to 10 is (if you can't find anything else to spend your money on) a great idea. Maxed gems on a low level character is such a great improvement. 
If LLC picks up once we go live with pvp, it will be essential for twink builds. 
At this time, its 3 gems of the same tier + gold and the page/tome/++

Once 1.03 comes out, blizzard has been quoted saying the cost will be reduced to 2 of each gem instead of three! You might want to wait for that!

> Post Release Update
>   There was a big blog post today about the the current game design of Diablo III. If you missed it make sure to check it our here. Some key points can be found below, but you really should check out the full post. (http://www.diablofans.com/news/1222-diablo-iii-game-design-update/)
>   Statistics on builds and other interesting things.
>   Patch 1.0.2, which has been in development since the game launched, should go live sometime within the next week
>   In patch 1.0.3 they will be showing the ilvl budget on level 60+ items to make it easier to understand why blues at times are stronger than other level 60 legendaries.
>   In Patch 1.1 legendaries will be getting a boost. However this will only affect new drops.
>   Blacksmith will have its gold cost and page cost reduced.
>   You will only need two gems in order to combine for the next gem, up to Flawless Squares

Hope this helps!

Comment: Is there any link i can find for update hints to 1.03? Where are you getting this info from?

Comment: Not that i don't believe you, I just want to read. :P

Comment: The 2 gem cost will be only for flawless square and below, so it won't really effect the higher level gems.

Comment: Looking for it, ill get back and edit my main post once I find it!

Comment: Mr. November is correct about the flawless square comment. (unfortunately, but it makes sense.)

Comment: I think its this one: http://us.battle.net/d3/en/blog/6018173

Comment: Heh, could be, my work blocks battle.net so I have to go thru other sources :-(

Comment: Ah, crafty bosses these days. :P

Comment: Heh, I'm just glad they didn't snag em all. Im suprised this didn't take a hit mainly because its "gaming.stackexchange.com"